# R keep a character part of the selection gsub

Tags: r, gsub, text-formatting

I have a list in which I have elements like `America1` or `Europe2`. It is in fact the way I get footnotes from text-mining a PDF.
I want to remove these trailing numbers, but I also have numbers that I want to keep. 
What I want is therefore onlly to remove digits after a character.

I can remove both the character and number by using `gsub("[az]\\d")`, but my attempt to keep the character have been unsuccessful, that is :

```
x=c("America2", "Europe2 3", "4.6", "Asia4 7.6")
y <- x %>% gsub("[a-z]\\d", "\\1", .)
> y
[1] "Americ"  "Europ 3" "4.6"     "Asi 7.6"
```

What have I misunderstood ?

Comment: In `[a-z]\d`, you did not use the capturing parentheses, so `\1` is not initialized Use `gsub("([[:alpha:]])\\d+", "\\1", .)`

Comment: The \\x only works when you have beforehand "numbered" them by putting them bewteen parentheses ?

Comment: `\X` is the Xth parenthesized pattern part capture. See the quote from the linked thread: *You can reference the groups in `gsub`, for example, using `\\n` where `n` is the nth capture group*

Comment: If I may, why the need for two brakcets `[[]]` and why the `+` ?

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` matches any letter. `+` matches 1+ consecutive occurrences.